# Screencasting shows black on Ubuntu 16.04 Guest in Virtual Box (LM host)

Tags: virtualbox, screencast

I'm running a Linux Mint host with an Ubuntu 16.04 Guest using Virtual Box.  When I try to screen capture the VM, I just get a black screen (but can see the mouse).

I've tried running [silentcast](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast) and [simplescreenrecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) from within the Ubuntu guest, but the result is a black screen.

When I try to use the built-in VirtualBox screencast, I get this error:

```
Failed to enable video capturing for the virtual machine Ubuntu16.04 (Hackerspace).

Unable to start video capturing (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER). 

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} Callee:
IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

Is there something I can do to get these programs working properly?

Comment: What is the result when recording with the inbuilt video capture feature of virtual box?

Comment: I get an error.  I edited the question with the error info.

Comment: Is this an issue with 3d acceleration turned off? Seen under Settings --> Display --> Acceleration

Comment: Enable 3D acceleration is ticked, Enable 2D acceleration is grayed out.